# How can i parse the following?

Tags: android, json

I am getting response in this format 
(Whole response)

I have tried the following code so far but getting error

```
private String connect(String url) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    String returnString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String res = convertStreamToString(instream);

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(res);

                String f = jsonObj.getString("Result");

                f = f.trim();

                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! "+f);

                String s= jsonObj.getString("About"); 
                System.out.println("@@@@@@ "+s); 

                JSONArray get = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");



                // lets loop through the JSONArray and get all the items 
                for (int i = 0; i < get.length(); i++) { 
                    // printing the values to the logcat 
                    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&"+get.getJSONObject(i).getString("About").toString()); 
                    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&"+get.getJSONObject(i).getString("AboutMeText").toString());  
                } 



                instream.close();
            }
        } else {
            returnString = "Unable to load page - "
                    + response.getStatusLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        returnString = "Connection failed; " + ex.getMessage();
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        returnString = "JSON failed; " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return returnString;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Everytime i am trying to parse it it gives me json failed exception and says no value for..
Please let me know if i am making any mistake here.

Comment: instead of your convertstremtostring, there is EntityUtils.toString (off topic, sorry)

Comment: It's an invalid JSON string. Check using http://www.jsonlint.org/

Comment: In your json, I don't see any string in the object which key would be GetConfigResult. That seems logical to me. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @Rajesh: it says it is a valid JSON!!

Comment: could you post your jsonresponse correctly so that i'll help you.Now which you posted that is not a valid jsonresponse.check it[either here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) or [here](http://www.jsonlint.org/)

Comment: @Harish  i have edited the whole json data check it.

Comment: @Shrikant Once check it.It is invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is not valid do you want this?

```
{
"Result": [
    {
        "About": "",
        "AboutMeText": {}
    }
]
}
```

Comment: After About it is like 
"AboutMeText":[{}]

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler way is to use GSON. (all code from memory so...)

for `{Result: ["{"About":"","AboutMeText":[{}]]}`  I'd create a class

```
public class Result {
 private String About;
 private String AboutMeText;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Then in order to deserialize

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Result.class);
```